# File manager how to SCP,SSH key files,Basic SSH,FTP,Windows Share,WebDAV(HTTP),Secure WebDAV(HTTPS)?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus

How can i do from Ubuntu default file manager, "connect to remote server" with different services such as "AMAZON cloud connnect using SSH key file, **SCP**, General SSH, FTP, Public FTP, Windows Share, WebDAV (HTTP), Secure WebDAV(HTTPS)".

Note: Using different applications for each services is no more required, Like in Fedora 15, Gnome 3. Where they had all shifted as default, easy to upload large files even connected over VPN or etc. Can we have this in Ubuntu/How?

Comment: Could you be more clear ? Ubuntu uses `nautilus` the default file manager of gnome so basically it should be same unless gnome3 has added some additional functionality to nautilus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this out of nautilus the same way as you did in Fedora (Note: the menu bar is at the very top with unity)

[image]

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for DAV shares from 10.10 onwards